# Excel Automation without Interop

Tags: excel, interop, excel-automation

We have excel reports which are having connections from external sources. We need to refresh these connections in a day twice. We are already having an application for this which uses Interop. Now we want to get rid of Interop since server side office automation is not supported by Microsoft anymore. Is there any other way to refresh the excel connection in a scheduled manner.

PS. I have read that OpenXML doesn't have this data connection refresh functionality in that.